# ant copy directory and add name to destination

Tags: ant

I'm trying to copy directory with it's content using ant script, also I want to set current date as directory name on destination.

This is the script that I write:

```
<property name="current_date" value="${build.date}"/>
<copy todir="T:/Ali/backup/reports/${current_date}">
    <fileset dir="log/current" />
</copy>
```

After executing the ant script
the directory name at the destination is ${current_date} and not actual current name.

any help!!

Answer (score 1):

Ant has a built-in `tstamp` task which can get the current date:

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="TODAY_US" pattern="yyyy-mmmm-dd" locale="en,US"/>
</tstamp>
<copy todir="T:/Ali/backup/reports/${TODAY_US}">
    <fileset dir="log/current" />
</copy>
```